# External HDD not detected

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, chkdsk, hard-drive-recovery

I have **Seagate Expansion Portable Drive** Model: **SRD00F1** which is out of warranty unfortunately. There were problems in it which I was trying to fix.

From these Problems that have been trying to fix in my external HDD before it came undetectable:

1. At some files, the reading becomes very slow tremendously!
2. Some files were corrupted & some were disappeared out of hand!

The main problem now isn't these problems, it is when I tried to fix them using disk recovery software I've ended up with the disability to detect my external hdd although it was readable and detectable with them.

What I've tried to fix the previously mentioned problems:

1. I've used **Norton Utilities 16** >> **Disk Doctor** >> **Surface Scan**. It took a lot of time and seemed not responding, so I've interrupted it. The disk was detectable after this process normally.
2. I've used **PC Tools Disk Suite** >> **Surface Scan**. It took a lot of time and it displayed a lot of errors of the kind `The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters`. And finally it ended up with an error, with an error code I forgot to record unfortunately, interrupting the process. The disk wasn't detectable for a while but was slowly responding after this process, then became undetectable at all.

What I've tried to fix the disability to detect my external HDD problem:

1. I've changed the USB Ports I plug-in my external HDD at. ***Make No Sense.***
2. I've tried other computers to plug-in my external HDD at. ***Make No Sense.***
3. I've tried to safely remove my external HDD, but nothing happens, then I end up with removing without the safely removing readiness popup message.
4. I've opened the **Device Manager** and  surprisingly I've found that it's detectable by the device manager in **Storage Controllers** >> **USB Attached SCSI (UAS) Mass Storage Device**. But not detectable by **File Explorer**.

My drive sounds normal but is not detected, as there is no beeping sound or clicking noises!

I need to make my external HDD detectable again, and solve the two problems mentioned at first!

**UPDATE: Please don't tell me that there is no solution as I'm sure that the problem is a software related, not physical! Any software problem can be solved via DIY approaches so please don't tell me to give up while there is a hope!**

Comment: Sounds like the drive is on its last gasp - forget about trying to fix it & concentrate on getting your data off it & onto a new drive, before you make it even worse than you have.

Comment: If you are4 losing your data, it means the HDD is about to fail, just replace it.  There is NOTHING you, as an end user, except transfer the data you can transfer onto another HDD.

Comment: @Tetsujin How is the drive seems to be on its last gasp!!! I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't physical, it's a software logical related problem!!

Comment: "The disk does not have enough space to replace bad clusters" It's full & it's bad - recover your data before it's too late.

Answer (score 1):

Your hard drive is dying. Copy all your data off of it. If the hard drive is not being recognized, you can power cycling (on and off). If you are desperate to get data off, you can trying [freezing your hard drive](http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux).

Comment: How it is dying?! The problem isn't physical at all! I think that it's a firmware or logical software problem!

Comment: If you think it is a firmware or software problem, I can not help you. When you say files are reading slow and files are corrupt, those classic signs of a dying hard drive.

Comment: Also, there is a saying... ["you catch more files with honey than you do with vinegar"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39619/origin-and-meaning-of-you-catch-more-flies-with-honey-than-you-do-with-vinegar)

Comment: I'm sorry if you understood that I downplay your suggestion, but I really don't mean that! May be expression falsified because English is my second language! I'm quite sure that the problem is a software problem because the hard drive is being read by Device Manager normally but not the File Explorer!!! Pls check this http://imgur.com/W5HMkdg!

Answer (score 0):

Yup. This sounds like a failing hard drive. Your best bet is to give up on it and get another one. You could try recovering the data at some other time if you wish. There are various utilities that will do that. I used one called Disk Doctors NTFS Data Recovery.

http://www.diskdoctors.net/ntfs-data-recovery/software.html

It worked on failing drives and formatted drives by going sector by sector. It can take quite a long time, but the process can be helpful. It will determine if something is unrecoverable during the recovery process.

Comment: I can't believe that there is no solution for making my hdd return to work normally again as I'm pretty sure that the problem isn't physical!!

Comment: The fact that it worked previously and now doesn't is indicative of a hard drive failure - been there and done that scene before more than once!